# Rendering multiple objects in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I am using advanced OpenDL methods (VBO, VBA, ...) to render over screen. Currently I abstracted vbo, vba, index buffer, texture, and shader to a class called 'Object2D'.

I tried to render two objects on screen. I saw that when the same shader is applied to both objects it works fine; but if the two objects are rendered with two different shader script, only the one rendered last is visible to screen.

Here is `Object2D::render()`:

```
void Render()
{
    if(check_status())
    {
        sh.bind(); //shader
        vb.Bind(); //vertex buffer
        ib.Bind(); //index buffer
        tex.bind(); //texture buffer
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,6,GL_UNSIGNED_INT,NULL);
    }
    else{}
    //sh.unbind();
}
```

And here is the drawing function (assume the two 2D objects are `obj` and `box`):

```
void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); //refresh/..
    box.sh.setUniformMat4x4("m_projection",GL_FALSE,1,&m_PROJ[0][0]);
    box.Render();
    obj.sh.setUniformMat4x4("projection_matrix",GL_FALSE,1,&m_PROJ[0][0]);
    obj.sh.setUniformMat4x4("view_matrix",GL_FALSE,1,&view_transform[0][0]);
    obj.Render();
    glFlush();
}
```

And this is the shader binded to `box`:

```
#shader vertex
#version 330 core 

layout(location = 0) in vec4 positions;
uniform mat4 m_projection;
void main(void)
{
    gl_Position=m_projection*positions;
}

#shader fragment
#version 330 core

layout(location=0) out vec4 color;

void main(void)
{
    color=vec4(1.0,0.4,0.3,1.0);
}
```

and this shader is binded to obj:

```
#shader vertex
#version 330 core 

layout(location = 0) in vec4 positions;
layout(location=0) in vec2 texture_coodrinate;
out vec4 p;
out vec2 TexCoord;
uniform mat4 projection_matrix;
uniform mat4 view_matrix;

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position=projection_matrix*view_matrix*positions; //modelvi
    p=projection_matrix*view_matrix*positions;;
    TexCoord=texture_coodrinate;
}

#shader fragment  
#version 330 core

layout(location=0) out vec4 color;
in vec4 p;
in vec2 TexCoord;
uniform vec4 U_color;   
uniform sampler2D tex_;

void main(void)
{
    ;
    U_color;
    color=texture(tex_,TexCoord);
}
```

My problems are:

- Two of the objects aren't being rendered if until and unless both the shaders are same
- Unbinding the shader result in no rendering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before setting up uniforms, you should bind the shader as well (with `glUseProgram`, i guess that's what the `.bind()` method does in your case). [See GLSL common mistakes](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/GLSL_:_common_mistakes#glUniform_doesn.27t_work).

Comment: `int bind()
 {
  if(isready())
  glUseProgram(ID);
  else
     return -1;
 }` ID is the unsigned program generated by opengl (shader program)

Comment: But why the both objects with different shader are not being rendered toughter...i mean one which is last rendered remaines other is missing